# Golang smtp SendMail fail for email group

Tags: go, smtp

I'm using Golang's smtp package and it's failing to send an email if the email is a Google email group containing 10 or so people in it. It works perfectly if I just email to a single gmail recipient. I have no idea where to start looking. Doesn't look like they have anything in the API documentation.

```
auth := smtp.PlainAuth(
    "",
    "erased for privacy reasons...",
    "erased for privacy reasons...",
    "smtp.gmail.com",
)
msg := []byte(
    "To: " + *email + "\r\n" +
        "Subject: External health check failure!\r\n\r\n" +
        "some stuff:\n\n" + "\r\n")
smtpErr := smtp.SendMail(
    "smtp.gmail.com:587",
    auth,
    "",
    []string{"erased for privacy reasons..."},
    msg,
)
if smtpErr != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Email alert failed with the following error: %v\n", smtpErr)
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: No error message takes place

Comment: Figured out the answer... I'm supposed to use TLS authentication in this specific case ( not sure why exactly ). But that fixed it for me